# Source Code Option is not showing in Plist

Tags: xcode8

In my Xcode 8.3.2 open as source code option is not displaying.[image]

Comment: you can open it with any external editor like `sublime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Your `plist` `type` is `Property List Binary`

Change `type` in File inspector 
To `Default - Property List XMl`

[image]

Comment: As i changed to Property List XML after that only open as property option diisplay but cant displaying open as source code

Comment: How can i change as Property List XML as default ?
(Current my default is Property List Text)

Comment: Select your `plist` and in right side File Inspector you can see type option Then try to right click on `plist` and check is source code option available

Comment: Yeah I can found that option but when I selecting Property List XML then  it is only displaying Property List XML but not "Default - Property List XML".

Comment: When I am Selecting Property List XML then I am only seeing open as property but not open as source code

Comment: Try to change `XML` and check because it is working for me

Comment: Yes XML is working. But I can change XML as default property?

Comment: I don't know about it but if you think my answer is helpful to you so you can accept and up-vote it